# I cannot install a library inside a sub folder

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting a weird error every time I try to run `npm install --save  openzeppelin-solidity@2.3`:

```
sha3@1.2.2 install C:\Users\hassa\OneDrive\Desktop\Documents\block\nd1309-p2-Decentralized-Star-Notary-Service-Starter-Code\app\node_modules\sha3
node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\hassa\OneDrive\Desktop\Documents\block\nd1309-p2-Decentralized-Star-Notary-Service-Starter-Code\app\node_modules\sha3>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\hassa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\hassa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! find VS 
gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Users\hassa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:121:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\hassa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:74:16
gyp ERR! stack     at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio2013 (C:\Users\hassa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:351:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\hassa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:70:14
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\hassa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:372:16
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\hassa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:54:7
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\hassa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\util.js:33:16
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:315:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22000
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\hassa\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\hassa\OneDrive\Desktop\Documents\block\nd1309-p2-Decentralized-Star-Notary-Service-Starter-Code\app\node_modules\sha3
gyp ERR! node -v v14.15.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sha3@1.2.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sha3@1.2.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hassa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-12-07T15_16_26_277Z-debug.log
```

This error happens only when I run the command in a sub folder (not the main folder).

and to reproduce this error we do the following

we clone the following repo https://github.com/udacity/nd1309-p2-Decentralized-Star-Notary-Service-Starter-Code

and we change the directory to **app** and then we run this command `npm install --save  openzeppelin-solidity@2.3`

please help me

Comment: "You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio"  How do you feel about it telling you that?  Do you feel like that's something you need to do?  It says "For more information consult the documentation at: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows" what did you think after reading that documentation?